# How to save already filled data field values before saving them into the database in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have implemented React application with Redux for conference management application. There, I implemented a form to insert the conference information to add a new conference.

---

**Problem**
The problem that I'm currently facing is if the user navigates to a separate page at the middle of the form filling and when the user comes back, all the data that he/she filled is gone. They need to start filling the form again.

---

Is there any methods to save the already inserted data in some persistence place, and when the user again comes back to the page, load those already filled data into the necessary fields?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. You can use SessionStorage to store the data temporally.
[source](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3834-saving-temporary-form-data-to-the-sessionstorage-api-in-angular-9-1-9.htm)